# Gradle build failed after moving dependency folder

Tags: android, gradle

I am currently having a problem where moving a dependency folder makes the build fail and leaves me with an error that seems out of place.

I have a project that imports a module `common`. The folder structure is as follows:

```
|_android_app
|_common_common
```

And the `settings.gradle` is as follows:

```
include ':app', ':common'
project(':common').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../common/common')
```

Gradle syncs with no problem and everything works correctly. But a problem arises when I try to move this `common` module to other folder, leaving the folder structure:

```
|_android_app
|_common_android_common
```

And the settings:

```
include ':app', ':common'
project(':common').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../common/android/common')
```

Then I get this error which seems out of place:

```
No variants found for ':common'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at:
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidModule.deliverModels(AndroidModule.kt:135)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:80)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProvider.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:52)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:246)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:116)
```

Why changing the location of the module causes the gradle sync to fail?

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with what is described in the error. I actually forgot to specify the version of a lib that I reference in the common project:

```
implementation "com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:$rootProject.segmentVersion"
```

So, adding this to `buildscript.ext` in the root project, solved the problem:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    segmentVersion = '4.+' 
  }
}
```